# What are the rules of privilege reputation changes for beta sites?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reputation requirements compared](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared)

I've joined the recently-opened anime.se, and noticed that the rep amount needed to get certain privileges there is really small (it was just 2k for the "trusted user". Now, after 1 week in beta, the scores have shifted, increasing by 2 times - so now it's 4k for "trusted user" winch is still nothing compared to 20k here on SO. As I understand from searching the meta, the privileges themselves are based just on that rep requirement: so if, for example, a user has 2krep needed for Privilege A, and the next day the rep needed for that privelege is increased, the user loses it immediately.

Are these changes being done automatically, or manually by SE staff? And based on what criteria are they changed (i.e. each 7 days, each 100 users, etc)?

Comment: There are only three tiers: private beta, public beta and graduated. See [Reputation requirements compared](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58587/reputation-requirements-compared) for the exact list.

Comment: @MadScientist, ah, thank you! I tried to search for a post like that, but failed. I'll vote to close this as a duplicate.